# Tracking Object Position - Firing on a Trajectory

Tags: physics, projectile-physics, trajectory

How can I calculate the position of an object after "firing" it from a fixed point?

I am to create a small game - most likely with canvas (pure HTML, JS based) or Adobe Flash - in which the player fires objects at other obstacles in order to clear them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to look at [this question](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/13924/projectile-motion-arrow) and [this one](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/1041/realistic-trajectory-of-a-projectile).

Assuming you are not using a physics engine/library that will handle the motion for you (and simply call back in to your code when a collision event occurs), you probably want to simulate [projectile motion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projectile_motion) (also [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trajectory_of_a_projectile), [here](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/traj.html), and in general [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equations_of_motion)).

Answer (score 2):

Good old physics will help you here. Specifically the equations of motion: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equations_of_motion

If you want to simulate projectile motion (as in an arc) there's plenty of information for that too:

http://www.ajdesigner.com/phpprojectilemotion/vertical_velocity_equation.php

http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/traj.html

http://library.thinkquest.org/28388/Mechanics/Motions/Projectile.htm