# Launching projectile from a "canon"

Tags: unity, physics, bullet-physics

I'm working on "Scorched earth"-like game just for learning purpose. I can't figure out how to launch the projectile from my tank's position, with a power of X ([0,100]),at an angle of Y ([-180,180]).

Comment: Also see here: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/14298/tracking-object-position-firing-on-a-trajectory

Comment: @Byte56 I looked at the Arrow post, the difference is I don't know the destination, I just know the initial pos, the initial velocity, and the initial angle. It's not really a duplicate but well.

Comment: If you know the initial pos, velocity and angle, then where is your problem?

Comment: @tkausl Just bad at mathematics.